# Transposing Data in Spark Sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, transpose

I have a data set as follows :

| branch_id | branchid_ctdi | equipment_type | forecast_group | final_pass_yield | device_condition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chennai | chennai | xd3 | a7 | 97.94% | U |
| chennai | chennai | xd4 | a7 | 96.94% | U |
| chennai | chennai | xd3 | a7 | 95.94% | N |

I need this data to be transposed to :

| branch_id | branchid_ctdi | equipment_type | forecast_group | equipment_type_2 | final_pass_yield | final_pass_yield_2 | device_condition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chennai | chennai | xd3 | a7 | xd4 | 97.94% | 96.94% | U |
| chennai | chennai | xd3 | a7 |  | 95.94% |  | N |

I tried the query below but i get the output as follows:

| branch_id | branchid_ctdi | equipment_type | forecast_group | equipment_type_2 | final_pass_yield | final_pass_yield_2 | device_condition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chennai | chennai | xd3 | a7 | xd4 | 97.94% | 96.94% | U |
| chennai | chennai | xd3 | a7 |  | 95.94% |  | N |
| chennai | chennai | xd4 | a7 | xd3 | 96.94% | 97.94% | U |

Note: My dataset will have many records with different branch id, forecast group combinations but for a given, branch_id, branchid_ctdi, forecast_group, device_condition there could be different equipmen_types with corresponding final_pass_yield and lets assume there will be only max two records per combination

````
SELECT 
    src.branch_id, 
    src.branchid_ctdi, 
    src.equipment_type, 
    src2.equipment_type AS equipment_type_2, 
    src.forecast_group, 
    src.final_pass_yield, 
    src2.final_pass_yield AS final_pass_yield_2,
    src.device_condition
FROM 
    initial_load_stg1 src
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT branch_id, equipment_type,forecast_group,final_pass_yield,device_condition FROM initial_load_stg1 WHERE equipment_type IS NOT NULL )src2 
ON 
    src.branch_id = src2.branch_id 
    AND src.forecast_group = src2.forecast_group 
    AND src.device_condition = src2.device_condition 
    AND src.equipment_type <> src2.equipment_type
ORDER BY 
    src.branch_id, 
    src.equipment_type; ```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i need to transpose my dataset from rows to columns.